# Unable to download packages from Country server

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, permissions, guake

Following error is displayed as I tried to download guake from my terminal:
Why is this forbidden error displayed?
How can I be able to download it from my country server. It works fine When I try to download from Main Server.

As I tried to install VLC from the software center following error was displayed :

```
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle  /libhogweed2_2.7.1-1_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden
```

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsdl1.2/libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-composite0_1.10-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-   xv0_1.10-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb 403  Forbidden

```
root@techjhola:/home/techjhola# apt-get install guake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libglade2-0 libvte-common libvte9 python-glade2 python-vte
Suggested packages:
python-gtk2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
guake libglade2-0 libvte-common libvte9 python-glade2 python-vte
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 137 not upgraded.
Need to get 472 kB/643 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,118 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libglade2-0 amd64 1:2.6.4-2
  403  Forbidden
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libvte-common all 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libvte9 amd64 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-vte amd64 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-glade2 amd64 2.24.0-3ubuntu3
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglade2/libglade2-0_2.6.4-2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte/libvte-common_0.28.2-5ubuntu1_all.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte/libvte9_0.28.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte/python-vte_0.28.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@techjhola:/home/techjhola#
```

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently? Maybe it's a temporary syncing issue.

Comment: happens from time to time for any variety of reasons beyond your control. This is why Ubuntu offers mirrors. If on goes down or is slow, use an alternate. Sometimes the main or primary servers get hammered hardest.

Comment: @muru I did it and  and now eben *apt-get update* doesnt work :/

Comment: Have you tried to change server / country ? Maybe it's a temporary problem with sources. Backup first : `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak` , make the change : `sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/np./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list`  , clear the old `sudo rm /var/list/apt/lists/* -rf` , create new sources `sudo apt-get update`